# PdoMenu modx revo 3 уровня

Tags: cms, modx

Подскажите как составить вывод меню на 3 уровня

```
<ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_main">
      <li class="catalog__item catalog__item_lvl1 js-catalog__item" data-disabled-lg>
        <a class="catalog__link catalog__link_lvl1 catalog__link_toggle js-catalog__toggle " href="javascript:void(0)">
          Каталог                            </a>
        <div class="js-catalog_ins catalog__ins">
          <ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_ins catalog__col_all">
            <li class="catalog__item catalog__item_ins catalog__toggle js-catalog__ins-toggle">
              <a class="catalog__link catalog__link_ins catalog__toggle_link hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md" href="javascript:void(0)">Диваны и кресла</a>
              <div class="catalog__grid catalog__lvl3 js-catalog__lvl3">
                <div class="catalog__col catalog__col_type-2">
                  <ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_ins">
                    <li class="catalog__item catalog__item_ins
    ">
      <a class="catalog__link catalog__link_ins catalog__link_heading" href="/cat/divany/">
        <span class="link link_default">ДИВАНЫ</span>
      </a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li> 
                        </ul>
                      </div>

                    </li>
    </ul>
```

я начал вот так

```
[[pdoMenu? 
    &level=`3` 
    &parents=`2`  
    &tplOuter=`@INLINE <ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_main">[[+wrapper]]<ul>`
    &tpl=`@INLINE <li class="catalog__item catalog__item_lvl1 js-catalog__item"  data-disabled-lg><a  class="catalog__link catalog__link_lvl1 catalog__link_toggle js-catalog__toggle " href="javascript:void(0)">[[+menutitle]]</a></li>[[+wrapper]]`
    &tplParentRow=`@INLINE <li class="catalog__item catalog__item_lvl1 js-catalog__item"  data-disabled-lg><a  class="catalog__link catalog__link_lvl1 catalog__link_toggle js-catalog__toggle " href="javascript:void(0)">[[+menutitle]]</a></li>[[+wrapper]]`
    &tplInner=`@INLINE <div class="js-catalog_ins catalog__ins"><ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_ins catalog__col_all">[[+wrapper]]<ul></div>`
    &tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li><a href="[[+link]]">[[+menutitle]]</a></li>`
]]
```

только здесь

```
&tplInner=`@INLINE <div class="js-catalog_ins catalog__ins"><ul class="catalog__list catalog__list_ins catalog__col_all">[[+wrapper]]<ul></div>`
```

вот этот див выводит отдельно и не вписывает в него li

```
<div class="js-catalog_ins catalog__ins">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как минимум, у вас `[[+wrapper]]` должен быть **перед** закрывающим `</li>`. Самую полную инфу по **PdoMenu**, особенно по чанкам, [здесь](https://modzone.ru/blog/2016/10/15/pdomenu-templates/) посмотрите

Comment: У меня в условиях сделан вывод всех ресурсов, кроме товаров из минишопа2, если это не важно, убери строку с where

Answer (score 0):

Вот так выводит 3 уровня (и само собой нужен файл бутстрап-стилей):

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                [[pdoMenu?
                    &startId=`0`
                    &where=`{"class_key:!=":"msProduct"}`
                    &level=`4`
                    &levelClass=`submenu`
                    &tplParentRow=`@INLINE
                    <li class="[[+classnames]] dropdown">
                        <a href="[[+link]]" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">[[+wrapper]]</ul>
                    </li>`
                    &tplOuter=`@INLINE [[+wrapper]]`
                ]]
    </ul>
</div>
```

и CSS

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {display: block;}
.dropdown-menu {min-width: 200px;}
li.submenu2.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu {left: 100%; top: 0;margin-top:4px;}
li.submenu2.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu a{background:#eee;}
li.submenu2.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu a:hover{background:#5C6C7F;}
li.submenu3.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu {left: 100%; top: 0;margin-top:4px;}
li.submenu3.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu a{background:#eee;}
li.submenu3.dropdown>ul.dropdown-menu a:hover{background:#5C6C7F;}
```